# Kivy label text needing to read from python variable

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create a python/kivy flashcard game.  I did this in python/tkinter and was able to pull a cell values from excel, convert to dictionary, & read front & back columns from excel in a random order.  Now I am trying this with kivy unsuccessfully. The working code below will self create a test example df with Front/Back columns (states/capitols).  The Kivy window should popup and present a small grey horizonal spinner menu bar at top of screen. If selected then you will see flashcards menu. Within this menu, it currently reads "Front Card Label" where it should read the python variable ( current_card["Front'] ) which is whatever state that was randomly selected in python code.

To explain a bit differently, I'm trying to get the Kivy / : / Label / Text to present the python dictionary current_card["Front"] variable. Whatever is chosen by the randomizer.

I have been trying to get a global variable to work but error always states variable as undefined. I have also read some posts regarding using ( from kivy.properties import StringProperty ) but I have yet to figure this out.

If someone could please help me past this hurdle I would appreciate it.  Then I can attempt my callback button assignments for Flip Card & Next Card.

Please let me know if further information is needed.  I Thank you for your time.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.spinner import Spinner
import pandas as pd
import pandas
import random
from random import randint
from kivy.properties import StringProperty

#----------------Test dataframe for flashcards
flash_df = [['Texas', 'Austin'], ['New Mexico', 'Santa Fe'], ['Iowa', 'Des Moines'], 
           ['Colorado', 'Denver']]
data = pd.DataFrame(flash_df, columns=['Front', 'Back'])
print(data)      #test Print Working
#----------------End of Test df______________


#------------Start Python script for random selection of dataframe
#data = pandas.read_excel("data/QA-Flashcards.xlsx", header=0, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols= 
        ['Front','Back'])
data.dropna(subset = ["Front"], inplace=True)
to_learn = data.to_dict(orient="records")
#print(to_learn)
current_card = random.choice(to_learn)
print(current_card)  #test Print Working
#--------------End Python script for random selection of dataframe

KV = """
<MainScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        # Button:
        #     text: 'Edit'
        #     on_press: root.goEdit()
        Label:
            text: 'Main Screen'
    
<ScreenMenu>:
    text: 'main'
    values: ('main', 'Flash Cards')
    pos_hint:{"x":0,"y":.97}
 
<flashcardsScreen>:
    Label: 
        text: 'Front Card Label'   #just a label text working 
    
        #text: (current_card["Front"])  #Trying to pull from above Python script variable!!!!!
        #text: app.current_card["Front"] #has no attribute 'current_card'
        #text: root.current_card
        pos: "-3dp", "175dp"
 
    Label:
        text: 'Back Card Label'
        pos: "-5dp", "-150dp"    
    
    Button:
        text: "Flip"
        size_hint: .25, .10
        pos: "100dp", "275dp"
    
    Button:
        text: "Next Card"
        size_hint: .25, .10
        pos: "500dp", "275dp"

"""


class MainScreen(FloatLayout):

    def goEdit(self):
        MyApp.build.screen_layout.remove_widget(MyApp.screen)
        screen = EditScreen()
        MyApp.screen = screen
        MyApp.screen_layout.add_widget(MyApp.screen)

class flashcardsScreen(FloatLayout):
    pass

class ScreenMenu(Spinner):
    pass

class MyApp(App):

    def build(self):
        Builder.load_string(KV)
        self.screen = None
        self.root = FloatLayout()
        self.screen_layout = FloatLayout()
        self.menu = ScreenMenu()
        self.root.add_widget(self.screen_layout)
        self.root.add_widget(self.menu)
        self.menu.bind(text=self.select_screen)
        self.show('main')
        return self.root

    def select_screen(self, *args):
        self.show(self.menu.text)

    def show(self, name='main'):
        if self.screen is not None:
            self.screen_layout.remove_widget(self.screen)
            self.screen = None
        if name == 'main':
            screen = MainScreen()
        elif name == 'Flash Cards':
            screen = flashcardsScreen()
        else:
            raise Exception('Invalid screen name')
        self.screen = screen
        self.screen_layout.add_widget(screen)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish that by using `StringProperty` in the `flashcardsScreen`:

```
class flashcardsScreen(FloatLayout):
    front_card_label = StringProperty('Abba')  # text for card front
    back_card_label = StringProperty('Dabba')  # text for card back

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(flashcardsScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        # ----------------Test dataframe for flashcards
        flash_df = [['Texas', 'Austin'], ['New Mexico', 'Santa Fe'], ['Iowa', 'Des Moines'],
                    ['Colorado', 'Denver']]
        data = pd.DataFrame(flash_df, columns=['Front', 'Back'])
        print(data)  # test Print Working
        # ----------------End of Test df______________


        # ------------Start Python script for random selection of dataframe
        # data = pandas.read_excel("data/QA-Flashcards.xlsx", header=0, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols=
        # ['Front', 'Back'])
        data.dropna(subset=["Front"], inplace=True)
        self.to_learn = data.to_dict(orient="records")
        self.next_card()

    def next_card(self):
        # print(to_learn)
        current_card = random.choice(self.to_learn)
        print(current_card)  # test Print Working
        # --------------End Python script for random selection of dataframe

        self.front_card_label = current_card['Front']
        self.back_card_label = current_card['Back']
```

And referencing those `StringProperties` in the kv:

```
<flashcardsScreen>:
    Label: 
        text: root.front_card_label
        pos: "-3dp", "175dp"

    Label:
        text: root.back_card_label
        pos: "-5dp", "-150dp"
```

Then, when you update those properties, the labels will be automatically updated.

Answer (score 1):

Good day. I recommend that you use [properties](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.properties.html). You could use a `StringProperty` that allows you to automatically update your Label text when it is changed. You simply update the string value whenever the function complete. I recommend using a callback function that contains that stream of code; to accept button callback arguments, to run the backend code, and to change the value on the label text. Access the Label text via its [id](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html#accessing-widgets-defined-inside-kv-lang-in-your-python-code).

Comment: Thank you Darrell for taking the time to help with this.  The String Properties was exactly what I needed to understand.  I was able to cobble a couple callback buttons to make the project work.  I appreciate your information.